# How to write/add attribute in rowTag of XML file generated through scala databrick

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have to  create structure like `<book book-id=123>` book is row tag. I am using databrick with scala to write XML.

```
df.repartition(1)
  .write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "category")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save("bookdetail")
```

How can I add attribute `book-id` in book `rowTag`?

Answer (score 0):

To can create attributes in XML by adding columns that start with special prefix.
From docs:

> attributePrefix: The prefix for attributes so that we can differentiate attributes and elements. This will be the prefix for field names. Default is _.

So in your case you only need to add an additional column to your dataset:

```
df
    .withColumn("_book-id", $"id") //this column is prefixed with _
    .repartition(1)
    .write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag", "category")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save("C:\\Users\\RK03GJ\\ProcesDevel\\dump")
```